# How to pass parameters to sam template with override-parameters with optional parameters

Tags: yaml, sam

I'd like to create a SAM template.yml containing lambda and several sqs's. I'd like to deploy it with parameters but not populate all the sqs's only some depending on the environment I need to deploy it on. How do I create a template with partial parameters populated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found how to do it in CloudFormation:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/conditionally-launch-aws-cloudformation-resources-based-on-user-input/

And here's how to do it in SAM template:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html

Answer (score 1):

For SAM templates, see these docs also for setting `parameter_overrides` via a `samconfig.toml` file:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html

You can specify the location of the config file with the `--config-file /path/to/samconfig.toml` argument.

Example `samconfig.toml` file with parameters configured:

```
version=0.1
[default.global.parameters]
parameter_overrides=[
  "TemplateInput1=Value1",
  "TemplateInput2=Value2"
]
```